PC turns off randomly
I need help with my mini PC. (Mini A5, CPU AMD Ryzen™ 7 5800H, 32GB DDR4, 512GB SSD (M.2 2280 PCIe Gen3x4)). PC turns off spontaneously when watching online video. I checked all elements and modules, power supply, memory, temperatures. I changed ssd m.2 to ssd sata, RAM, disconnected the Wi-Fi module from the board and the problem was not solved.
In all the different load tests it feels good, several hours of testing shows stable operation, memtest says everything is ok, OCCT works correctly in all modes. But as soon as I go to any browser, open YouTube, start a video in any quality, after 5-30 minutes it turns off as if it had been pulled out of the socket. If, after a sudden shutdown, you press the power button, it starts up as if nothing had happened. Please guide me what could this be? How can this be detected or corrected?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Since I've been having problems with something similar - I wonder if its the power supply. Its working fine under low loads, but when its loaded up, its shutting down.

Does it show the same problem in Vimeo.com? If you play a video in, say, Windows Media Player, does it show the same problem, or is it only videos in browsers?

Try booting from a Linux Live USB, such as Ubuntu Live, and viewing YouTube with the preinstalled browser. If the same issue occurs, then almost certainly, it's hardware-related, such as @JourneymanGeek comment on power supply.
